# In Ruby, why am I calling an instance variable from another class as a method?

Tags: ruby, class, instance-variables

I'm creating a basic tic-tac-toe game to keep up my "Ruby chops." In the Game class, I've only gotten the `generate_board` method to work using the code below. I can't seem to access the `@board` instance variable directly. Can anyone explain why I'm having to call it as a method, and how to avoid this? Thank you!

```
class Board
  def initialize
    @board = (1..9).to_a
  end
end

class Game
  attr_accessor :board

  def initialize
    generate_board
  end

  def generate_board
    new_board = Board.new
    @board = new_board.board
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance variable `@board` from the Board class is only accessible to other methods within the Board class. Since your method `generate_board` is outside of the Board class and within a different class, the `@board` instance variable from the Board class isn't accessible to the method in the Game class.

This in general is how instance variables work.

Answer (score 0):

On following [Sagarpandya Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34646347/3098330) You could write your code like this.

```
class Board
  def initialize
    @board = (1..9).to_a
  end
end

class Game
  attr_accessor :board

  def initialize
    generate_board
  end

  def generate_board
     Board.new
  end
end
p Game.new.generate_board
```